# Creating a multple choice quiz "game"

Tags: javascript, arrays

Some background: I am a near-total beginner learning to write HTML/CSS/JavaScript in my spare time.  Please be gentle. :)

A friend of mine, a professional programmer, put together a little project for me to work on in my spare time.

I am creating a quiz game that asks the user to match a randomly-selected English word to one of four Swedish words.  I have hit a small hitch: I do not know how to ensure that I am selecting the quiz answers that correspond to the question.

I have written the following variable:

```
var quiz = [
  {question: 'yes', answers: ['ja', 'förlåt', 'brör', 'samtal'], correct: 0},
  {question: 'sorry', answers: ['att försöka', 'förlåt', 'ingen', 'vår'], correct: 1}
];
```

And this function:

```
function engQuestion() {
  return quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)].question;
}
```

Within the HTML, I have this:

```
<div class="question">
  <h2>
    <script>
      document.write(engQuestion());
    </script>
  </h2>
</div>
```

This is my starting point.  I am trying to figure out how I can get the correct set of answers that match my question from the variable.  If I write:

```
return quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)].answers;
```

This will obviously give a random set of answers from the entire variable rather than a set of answers from the question's corresponding question array.

Is there a way to return both the questions and answers from the same random number?

The reason I have not found a good answer to this question is that most quiz questions pertain to a test where questions are given in a specific order rather than questions chosen randomly.

Thanks very much for any help.

I realize this seems quite simple to some of you, so I apologize for that.

Comment: You need to store the current random number so getting the answers belonging too the question. Try storing it with in a variable, cookie, or local storage.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started. You may then want to consider whether listing the answers in a list, e.g. `<ul>`, would be a good idea. Then, what happens when you click an answer.

```js
var quiz = [
  {question: 'yes', answers: ['ja', 'förlåt', 'brör', 'samtal'], correct: 0},
  {question: 'sorry', answers: ['att försöka', 'förlåt', 'ingen', 'vår'], correct: 1}
];

var engQuestion = function() {
  
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)
  
  let question = quiz[randomNumber].question
  let answers = quiz[randomNumber].answers
  
  document.getElementById('question').innerHTML= question
  document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML= answers

}

engQuestion();
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <h2 id="question">
  </h2>
   <h2 id="answers">
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess assign random number to a var and return quiz question and answer with that variable.

```
var ran_num = //random number 
return quiz[ran_num].question
```

The same can be used to return answers. I don't know if this is what you intended.